Tiling a square with rectangles.

Is there a way to tile a square with $5$ rectangles with edges in $[1,10]$. I am looking for an approach that turns this into a system of $10$ linear equations in $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_9, n_{10}$. All edge lengths need to be unique.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

For the tiling as in your image, first try finding $4$ disjoint pairs of lengths where the pairs give the same sum.

An example tiling.

@Lee, Does something like this help you:$\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 17 +\frac 1{43}+\frac 1{1806}=1$ ?

@sirous, not yet, but I'm sure there is a "secret" clue going on here. I notice there are 5 fractions here.  There are 5 rectangles. But I don't yet see the significance of your clue.

Note that rotating 90 degrees at a time yields 4 distinct solutions.

@Sirous, I am very interested in how your fraction equation relates to the problem at hand. Please give me more help.

@LeeBradley, This is one solution of equation $\frac 1 a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c +\frac 1d +\frac 1e=1$. This equation in elementary number theory can be use to divide a land in to five parts. If we add the condition that the land is square then few solutions may be acceptable.

@Sirous, Thank you so much. I have learned a bit about how to find a,b,c,d,e such the 1/a+1/b+ ...+1/e = 1. But try as I might, I can't see how to use the fact the "land" is a square to get the values for the edges of the 5 rectangles.

@Sirous, I shifted gears and thought Python might be just right.
http://primepuzzle.com/not.just.tiny.c/permutation.html

Here are necessary linear constraints:
\begin{align}
n_1 + n_2 &= n_3 + n_4 \\
n_1 &= n_6 + n_9 \\
n_3 &= n_8 + n_{10} \\
n_5 &= n_2 + n_9 \\
n_7 &= n_4 + n_{10}
\end{align}
It turns out that there are $16$ solutions with distinct $n_i\in\{1,\dots,10\}$:
\begin{matrix}
n_1 &n_2 &n_3 &n_4 &n_5 &n_6 &n_7 &n_8 &n_9 &n_{10} \\
\hline
4 &9 &7 &6 &10 &3 &8 &5 &1 &2 \\
4 &9 &8 &5 &10 &3 &7 &6 &1 &2 \\
6 &5 &8 &3 &9 &2 &10 &1 &4 &7 \\
6 &5 &10 &1 &9 &2 &8 &3 &4 &7 \\
7 &6 &4 &9 &8 &5 &10 &3 &2 &1 \\
7 &6 &10 &3 &8 &5 &4 &9 &2 &1 \\
8 &3 &6 &5 &10 &1 &9 &2 &7 &4 \\
8 &3 &9 &2 &10 &1 &6 &5 &7 &4 \\
8 &5 &4 &9 &7 &6 &10 &3 &2 &1 \\
8 &5 &10 &3 &7 &6 &4 &9 &2 &1 \\
9 &2 &8 &3 &6 &5 &10 &1 &4 &7 \\
9 &2 &10 &1 &6 &5 &8 &3 &4 &7 \\
10 &1 &6 &5 &8 &3 &9 &2 &7 &4 \\
10 &1 &9 &2 &8 &3 &6 &5 &7 &4 \\
10 &3 &7 &6 &4 &9 &8 &5 &1 &2 \\
10 &3 &8 &5 &4 &9 &7 &6 &1 &2 \\
\end{matrix}

Looks good. It is not clear to me how you actually solved this system. Did you just write down all 4-tuples that satisfied the first equation and then figure out the remaining variables by using the remaining equations?

I used a constraint programming solver.


Comment: Following my comments I give an example, as shown in picture. I used this relation:
$\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 1{10}+\frac 1{15}=\frac{15+10+3+2}{30}$
2, 3, 10 and 15 are one family of solutions of this equation:
$\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c+\frac 1d=1$

Of course this differs from the original problem in that it involves only 4 rectangles. And the tiled figure is not a square. Also, the factors of the areas are not unique. The only thing I see that's common to the original problem and this one is the use of the sum of 5 (now 4) reciprocals = 1. So ... still not seeing how to do my problem.
